# C++ pointer to member of derived class

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I don't understand what's happening here. I have a class `Base` that contains a field `a`. Now I create a `Derived` class that extend Base. I also have a template function that prints the field we want by passing a pointer-to-member template argument.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  Base(double a):a{a} {}
  double a;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived(double a) : Base(a) {}
};

template<double (Derived::*p)>
void print(Derived d) {
  std::cout << d.*p;
}

int main() {
  Derived d {10.0};
  print<&Derived::a>(d);
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work, but if I only use the base class:

```cpp
template<double (Base::*p)>
void print(Base b) {
  std::cout << b.*p;
}

int main() {
  Base b {10.0};
  print<&Base::a>(b);
}
```

It works as expected and prints `10.0`. How can I get it to work with the subclass?

The compiler says:

```
test.cpp:15:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:21:23: error: could not convert template argument ‘&Base::a’ from ‘double Base::*’ to ‘double Derived::*’
   print<&Derived::a>(d);
```

Comment: what is the error you get when you pass a `Derived`? Errors usually contain already good hints on what is wrong.

Comment: this question has the same problem as your last, it is not clear what you want to achieve and the example is too minimal to see why you would want to use a pointer to member as template parameter. Can you explain what is the motivation? There are different solutions, but which one to apply depends on why you want to have a pointer to member as tempalte parameter

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I'm guessing that there was some exploration going on when this happened and OP got curious. I don't think (I guess a lot) that circumventing the problem is the main goal, but to understand why the code is denied.

Comment: @TedLyngmo can be the case, and of course that doesnt make it less a good question. Only the answers would be different when there was concrete aim. Seems like "no, because" is sufficient as answer

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I see your point. Yes, if what I guessed is the main reason for asking, it could have been clearly stated. ... and now when I read it again "_How can I get it to work with the subclass_" - it is not so clear ...

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained the reason, I'm gonna explain the solution:

```cpp
template<typename T, double (T::*p)>
void print(T d) {
  std::cout << d.*p;
}


int main() {
  Derived d {10.0};
  print<Base, &Base::a>(d);
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/pM762f

I'm sure it's not what you'd hoped, but it's better than overloading each version. But I think it's best if you just find a better way of solving your problem because I know that this code here is not the problem you're actually facing because you could've just passed the double itself instead of member pointer.

So try to solve the problem in the context of your code not with this way. Here are some ideas that might solve your actual problem (if you have any):

- Use `enum`s
- Think about `std::map` if it's not too much
- You could use lambdas (they are `constexpr` now, so you can use them in your templates too)
- Think about moving the `print` function to the base class or even derived class
- Use higher order functions (too much lambdas essentially :D) instead of the whole object oriented solution.

and many many other solution which most of them probably won't help you (because I don't know the context of your code).

Answer (score 0):

This would be one of the examples when compiler message alone has all the [explanations](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PquNKi) one must want:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:21:23: error: no matching function for call to 'print<&Base::a>(Derived&)'
   21 |   print<&Derived::a>(d);
      |                       ^
<source>:15:6: note: candidate: 'template<double Derived::* p> void print(Derived)'
   15 | void print(Derived d) {
      |      ^~~~~
<source>:15:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:21:23: error: '&Base::a' is not a valid template argument for type 'double Derived::*'

   21 |   print<&Derived::a>(d);
      |                       ^
<source>:21:23: note: because it is a member of 'Base'
Compiler returned: 1
```

Answering a question in comment: template argument is not implicitly convertible to pointer to the member in base, and `static_cast` will not help, since for template non-type parameters which are pointers to members **have to be written in a form `&C::m`** (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members)

Comment: Why does it work if `double (Derived::*p)` is used as function parameter, rather than template parameter? There should also be an implicit conversion to the correct type, see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.mem#2. Why does it not apply?

Comment: Does `print<&Derived::a>(d)` become `print<&Base::a>(d)` somewhere along the line?

Comment: The conversion I mentioned above seems to be excluded for implicit conversion in template arguments, but neither GCC nor Clang accept the code, even with explicit `static_cast`, why is that?

Comment: @walnut I tried to probe both `g++` and `clang++` with different constructs to get an idea but the only one that sort of stood out was that `&Derived::a` became `&Base::a` - and therefor didn't match the signature. I'm terrible with templates so I'm just happy-probing though.

Comment: @walnut, the gcc error you are seeing is indeed a bug in diagnostic, but not a bug in the behavior. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members ("A pointer to non-static member object m which is a member of class C can be initialized with the expression &C::m exactly"). Added to answer.

Comment: I still don't understand. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/NaUQhV) is a more explicit step-by-step conversion to the correct type. What exactly is wrong with the `print` line, that isn't wrong with the `print2` line? I initialize the variable with `&C::m` exactly and nowhere on the cppreference site does it say that `&C::m` needs to be the template argument expression itself.

Comment: I don't understand why the implicit conversion is not done. What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

It is not that obvious, but the type of a member pointer to `a` is `double Base::*` no matter if it points to `a` in a `Derived` object or in a `Base` object. Your method only accepts a `Derived` parameter and only a pointer to a member in `Derived` as template parameter. If you want to allow different combinations you could write more overloads.

Comment: Why does it work if `double (Derived::*p)` is used as function parameter, rather than template parameter, if the type doesn't match?

Comment: @walnut good question. maybe rules for implicit conversions are different for template parameters...

Comment: Even an explicit `static_cast` to the correct template parameter type does not change the error message. So I don't think it has anything to do with implicit conversions.

Comment: I think https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.mem#2 should allow the conversion required here implicitly (if `&Derived::a` doesn't already have the correct type).

Comment: Nevermind, the conversion I mentioned above seems to be excluded for implicit conversion in template arguments, but even still, explicit `static_cast` (which I still don't see why it shouldn't work) yields strange error messages on gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/zDr36s